# segmentedcontrol / textfield / DidChange

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have a segmentedControl that give a string to a textfield. also i have 2 another textfields. one is for user input and the second for make a calculation from segmentedcontrol textfield and user input textfield. How can i automatically update the calculation textfield when segmentedcontrolindex will change.
For user input textfield the textfielddidchangemethod works. Thanks
[image]

```
@IBOutlet weak var segmentedcontrol: UISegmentedControl!



@IBOutlet weak var textf: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textf1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textf2: UITextField!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()




    textf.delegate = self
    textf1.delegate = self
    textf2.delegate = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@IBAction func textf1(sender: AnyObject) {


    let result = (textf.text! as NSString).doubleValue * (textf2.text! as NSString).doubleValue

    textf1.text = String(format:"%.2f", result)

}



@IBAction func segmentedcontrolAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    if(segmentedcontrol.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    {
        textf2.text = "5";
    }
    else if(segmentedcontrol.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
    {
        textf2.text = "10";
    }
    else if(segmentedcontrol.selectedSegmentIndex == 2)
    {
        textf2.text = "15";
    }


}
```

Comment: You don't need the `IBOutlet` for the segmented control. It's passed as the parameter `sender` in `segmentedcontrolAction`. And you can optimize your code writing `switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex { case 0: ... }` or even `textf2.text = "\((sender.selectedSegmentIndex + 1) * 5)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@IBAction func segmentedcontrolAction(sender: AnyObject) 
{

    if(segmentedcontrol.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    {
        textf2.text = "5";


    }
    else if(segmentedcontrol.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
    {
        textf2.text = "10";


    }
    else if(segmentedcontrol.selectedSegmentIndex == 2)
    {
        textf2.text = "15";


    }
       let result = (textf.text! as NSString).doubleValue * (textf2.text! as NSString).doubleValue
        textf1.text = String(format:"%.2f", result)

}
```

Comment: sometimes there is also a simple way :o)